# String split ,sort and compare with another column within a table SQL

Tags: sql, split, for-xml-path, stuff

```
Create Table #temp
(
Change varchar(20),
deleted_user_id int,
deleted_field_id int,
deleted_value   nvarchar (4000),
inserted_user_id  int,
inserted_field_id int,
inserted_value nvarchar (4000),
is_difference int,
)


insert into #temp values ('UPDATE','1', '11', '3,2,1,4','1','11','1,2,3,4','0')
insert into #temp values ('UPDATE','1', '12', '','1','12','1,2,3','0')
insert into #temp values ('UPDATE','2', '12', '1,2','2','12','','0')

select * from #temp
```

I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio

I am trying to compare the deleted value with inserted value. if there is a difference then set is_difference column to 1 or just return the rows.

so far I am thinking to do string split. maybe use stuff function. but not quite sure how to use all these to in a single query or is there any other option. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

this query works so far.

```
;with cte as 
(select isnull(deleted_user_id, inserted_user_id) as user_id,
    isnull(deleted_field_id, inserted_field_id) as field_id, 
    stuff(  
    (  
    SELECT ','+ value FROM STRING_SPLIT (deleted_value, ',') group by value order by value FOR XML PATH('')  
    ),1,1,'') as sorted_deleted_value , inserted_value 
    from #temp ) 
select * from cte where sorted_deleted_value <> inserted_value
```